# How to fix a jumpy animation in HTML caused by some jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a jQuery code that sets my menu position to fixed after it passes through a certain div. My problem is when I scroll past the div, my HTML makes a weird "jump" is there a way to make the elements stay where they are?

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>random</title>
  <!--   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css"> -->


</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="headcontainer"></div>
            <div id="menu">
                <div id="logo">
                    <p>Hier komt een logo</p>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Over</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                    <li>Producte</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <div class="text-box"></div>
                <div class="text-box"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
    #container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 100%;

    }

    #headcontainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: pink;

    }

    /* navigation */

    #menu {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:red;
        max-height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-top: none;
    }

    #menu li {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-left: 20px;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    #menu ul {
        float:right;
        height:100%;
        width: auto;
        line-height: 100px;
        margin-right:25px;
    }

    #menu ul li:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
        color: white;
    }

    #logo {
        height: 50px;
        width: auto;
        background-color: red;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 60px;
    }

    /*content*/
    #content {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:10000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

    .text-box {
        width:40%;
        height:auto;
        background-color:blue;
        min-height:100px;
        float:left;
        margin-left:5%;
        margin-right:5%;
        margin-top:50px;
    }

    </style>
```

jQuery code:

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $( "#headcontainer" ).height()) {
            $('#menu').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
        } else {
            $('#menu').css('position', 'static');
        }
    });
```

You can find a fiddle showing my issue [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oaLhehhw/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening, because when you have set the position to fixed, thus losing its height and causing the document to shift to the top.

Add the height of the div as top padding using `position:fixed`

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $( "#headcontainer" ).height()) {
        $('#menu').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
        var divHeight = $('#menu').outerHeight();
        $('body').css('padding-top',divHeight);
    } else {
        $('#menu').css('position', 'static');
        $('body').css('padding-top','0');
    }
});
```

You can find a workind demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oaLhehhw/1/).

Answer (score 4):

you can add margin-top to content div

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $( "#headcontainer" ).height()) {
    $('#menu').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
    $('#content').css('margin-top', '42%');
} else {
    $('#menu').css('position', 'static');
    $('#content').css('margin-top', '0');
}
});
```

your jsfiddle > https://jsfiddle.net/oaLhehhw/2/

Answer (score 2):

This is because you change your position state from static to fixed, means that your further elements now have free space to jump up because there is nothing.. you can use the following fix in your jQuery code that puts small margin-top setting to your further elements (#content).

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $( "#headcontainer" ).height()) {
            $('#menu').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
            $('#content').css('margin-top', '200px'); // this is example.
        } else {
            $('#menu').css('position', 'static');
        }
    });
```

Just calculate it exactly and check cross-browser support. However I don't suggest to use such structure. Better probably to put your topmenu in separate div box and work with it within that box.

Comment: `$('#content').css('margin-top', '200px'); // this is example.` if this is example then what is the correct margin to give??

Comment: It can be $("#menu").height(), but as we have height set in CSS why not to say it exactly as it is set there rather using jQuery calculation which is resource consumption ;-)

Comment: height may be vary in responsive layout...100px height in desktop could be 200px in mobile. So later instead of using if condition for screens its better to calculate height because we can't assume that css and html will never change and calculating height is just a nano seconds job which will not consume any **RESOURCE** as such..

Comment: You are right Gaurav. I just wanted to keep the entire concept as simple as possible. As the topic starter gentleman is probably CSS / jQuery newbie. But your input is great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
clear: both;
```

into the #content element in order to prevent floating.

.menu should be wrapped with new element (with same height) becouse when you are changeing position property to fixed elements beneath goes higher.